# Can not execute Windows gui process from service running under non-interactive account

Tags: windows, windows-services, win32gui, win32-process

I logged-in as UserA. There is service running under account UserB. When the service executes new process having gui, the new process starts without gui.
I expect it to behave as if I "run as" with different user.

From the service I tried `system` and `CreateProcess`. The same result.

Comment: Since Windows Vista, services run exclusively in a non-interactive session. If they run a GUI app, you won't be able to see the GUI. So you need to run the GUI app in a user session instead, such as with `CreateProcessAsUser()` using the user token from UserA's session.

Comment: I have to have GUI app be running under UserB account

Comment: Just because the service is running as UserB doesn't mean it is running in UserB's session. User logins and User sessions are two different things. If you are trying to make a service run a GUI in UserA's session with UserB's account, then you have some work to do. Have the service obtain UserB's user token, duplicate it, assign UserA's session ID to it, and then pass it to `CreateProcessAsUser()`

Comment: When I view the service in taskviewer I see UserB, so I do for the executed process. The only problem it's with no GUI.

Comment: Again, a service always runs in session 0, regardless of the user it runs as. And since Windows Vista, SESSION 0 CANNOT SHOW GUIS! So you MUST instruct `CreateProcessAsUser()` to create the GUI process in a separate interactive user session, regardless of which user account you assign to the process.

Comment: BTW, just for experiment, I launched from the server another "intermediate" process without GUI and executed GUI process from the "broker" - the same result. On other hand, If I do cmd "run as UserB" then all executions from the cmd show GUI.

Comment: When using CreateProcessAsUser() from the service, which user/password I should supply with to the call?

Comment: `CreateProcessAsUser()` doesn't take a username/password, it takes a handle to a user token. You are probably thinking of `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` instead. Since your service is already running as UserB, to run a new process as UserB in another session, use the service's existing user token, which you can get from `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess())` (don't use `GetCurrentProcessToken()`), then duplicate with `DuplicateTokenEx()`, modify the dupe's session ID with `SetTokenInformation()`, then pass the dupe to `CreateProcessAsUser()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &hPToken);
DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, &hDup);
DWORD actvS = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
SetTokenInformation(hDup, TokenSessionId, (void*)&actvS, sizeof(DWORD));
STARTUPINFO si;
GetStartupInfo(&si);
si.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
si.lpDesktop = "Winsta0\\default";
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
BOOL result = CreateProcessAsUser(hDup,
 NULL,
 "D:\\MFCt.exe",
 NULL,
 NULL,
 FALSE,
 NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
 NULL,
 NULL,
 &si,
 &pi);
 `

Comment: @RemyLebeau in service's code above, the launched app still wants to run in separate desktop.

Comment: As said above - there is no way to do it in Windows - by design, I guess starting from Vista indeed. Possible work-around, I think ,could be something like that: make special GUI, "proxy-appliation" (probably hidden) that communicates with your service and accepts requests to run processes. Then, create Windows TaskScheduler task that would start this application as UserB, each time any user logs-on.  Your service could then pass requests to "proxy-application" to run required process.